# ¿Por qué sucede esto?

Tags: html

tengo una duda de algo bien extraño que me está pasando en una página web la cual es:

[Mi Outlets](http://mioutlets.cl)

Al ingresar en la página web todo funciona bien se muestra el slider y más abajo los productos, pero algo extraño pasa al momento de agregar productos al carro.

- Si agrego 1 producto y después agrego otro producto el menú se daña de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al agregar dos productos el menu se coloca de esa forma, pero automático solo... que podría ser? algo super extraño.

Gracias.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [ask], no se entiende el problema

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estoy viendo que cambian muchísimo la estructura del HTML de un momento a otro.

Cuando tienes un ítem existe un `div(class="header-wrap"`) con dos hijos `"header-warp-holder" y "nav-wrap"`, en este caso, tiene la siguiente estructura:

```html
<div class="header-wrap" style="background: #fff !important;">
    <div class="header-wrap-holder" style="margin-top: 20px !important; background: #fff !important;">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo-container text-left">

            <a href="http://mioutlets.cl">
                <img class="hidden-xs" style="height: 150px !important; padding-left: 80px !important;"
                    src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/1598588156.png" alt="logo">

                <img class="logo hidden-md hidden-lg" style="height: 150px !important; padding-left: 80px !important;"
                    src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/1598588156.png" alt="logo">
            </a>

        </div>


        <!-- Search -->
        <div class="nav-search hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <form action="http://mioutlets.cl/product/all" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="vW2kK9yCh4BFkzd2bTTLjRpQJ6dbyooTRsO9dpQQ">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" style="width: 500px !important;">
                <button type="submit" class="search-button push-right">
                    <i class="icon icon_search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>


        <!-- Cart -->
        <div class="nav-cart-wrap hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="nav-cart right">
                <div class="nav-cart-outer">
                    <div class="nav-cart-inner">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-cart-icon">1</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-cart-container">
                    <div class="nav-cart-items">
                        <div class="nav-cart-item clearfix">
                            <div class="nav-cart-img">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/2020-08-11-05-41-12-file.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-title">
                                <a href="#">
                                    BANDA RESISTENCIA
                                </a>
                                <div class="nav-cart-price">
                                    <span>1 x</span>
                                    <span>$ 9990</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-remove">
                                <a href="#"><i class="icon icon_close"></i></a>
                            </div>

                        </div> <!-- end cart items -->

                        <div class="nav-cart-summary">
                            <span>Subtotal</span>
                            <span class="total-price">$ 9990</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="nav-cart-actions mt-20">
                            <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/cart" class="btn btn-md btn-dark"><span>Ver Carro</span></a>
                            <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/checkout" class="btn btn-md btn-color mt-10"><span>Ir a
                                    Pagar</span></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-cart-amount right">
                    <span>
                        Carro /
                        <a href="#"> $ 9990</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div> <!-- end cart -->

        </div>
    </div> <!-- end header wrap -->

    <div class="nav-wrap" style="background: #CC384D !important;">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li id="mobile-search" class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    <form action="http://mioutlets.cl/product/all" method="post" class="mobile-search relative">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="vW2kK9yCh4BFkzd2bTTLjRpQJ6dbyooTRsO9dpQQ">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
                        <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                            <i class="icon icon_search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl" style="color: #fff !important;">Inicio</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Accesorios" style="color: #fff !important;">Accesorios</a>
                </li> <!-- end categories -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Funcional" style="color: #fff !important;">Funcional</a>
                </li> <!-- end categories -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Pesas" style="color: #fff !important;">Pesas</a>
                </li> <!-- end categories -->

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/contact" style="color: #fff !important;">Contáctenos</a>
                </li>

                <li class="mobile-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://mioutlets.cl/login">INGRESAR</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://mioutlets.cl/register">REGISTRATE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul> <!-- end menu -->
        </div> <!-- end collapse -->
    </div> <!-- end col -->

</div>
```

Pero cuando añado un segundo ítem, tiene el mismo padre "header-wrap"  pero con una estructura muy diferente, lo que no debería de pasar, teniendo ahora solo el hijo `header-wrap-holder` y dentro de él tienes a `nav-wrap` lo que hace que se vea de manera rara

```html
<div class="header-wrap" style="background: #fff !important;">
    <div class="header-wrap-holder" style="margin-top: 20px !important; background: #fff !important;">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo-container text-left">

            <a href="http://mioutlets.cl">
                <img class="hidden-xs" style="height: 150px !important; padding-left: 80px !important;"
                    src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/1598588156.png" alt="logo">

                <img class="logo hidden-md hidden-lg" style="height: 150px !important; padding-left: 80px !important;"
                    src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/1598588156.png" alt="logo">
            </a>

        </div>


        <!-- Search -->
        <div class="nav-search hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <form action="http://mioutlets.cl/product/all" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="vW2kK9yCh4BFkzd2bTTLjRpQJ6dbyooTRsO9dpQQ">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" style="width: 500px !important;">
                <button type="submit" class="search-button push-right">
                    <i class="icon icon_search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>


        <!-- Cart -->
        <div class="nav-cart-wrap hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="nav-cart right">
                <div class="nav-cart-outer">
                    <div class="nav-cart-inner">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-cart-icon">2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-cart-container">
                    <div class="nav-cart-items">
                        <div class="nav-cart-item clearfix">
                            <div class="nav-cart-img">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/2020-08-11-05-41-12-file.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-title">
                                <a href="#">
                                    BANDA RESISTENCIA
                                </a>
                                <div class="nav-cart-price">
                                    <span>1 x</span>
                                    <span>$ 9990</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-remove">
                                <a href="#"><i class="icon icon_close"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-item clearfix">
                                <div class="nav-cart-img">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/2020-08-11-11-23-31-file.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-cart-title">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        PELOTA YOGA 65 CM
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="nav-cart-price">
                                        <span>1 x</span>
                                        <span>$ 7990</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-cart-remove">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon icon_close"></i></a>
                                </div>

                            </div> <!-- end cart items -->

                            <div class="nav-cart-summary">
                                <span>Subtotal</span>
                                <span class="total-price">$ 17980</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="nav-cart-actions mt-20">
                                <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/cart" class="btn btn-md btn-dark"><span>Ver
                                        Carro</span></a>
                                <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/checkout" class="btn btn-md btn-color mt-10"><span>Ir a
                                        Pagar</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-cart-amount right">
                        <span>
                            Carro /
                            <a href="#"> $ 17980</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end cart -->

            </div>
        </div> <!-- end header wrap -->

        <div class="nav-wrap" style="background: #CC384D !important;">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li id="mobile-search" class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
                        <form action="http://mioutlets.cl/product/all" method="post" class="mobile-search relative">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="vW2kK9yCh4BFkzd2bTTLjRpQJ6dbyooTRsO9dpQQ">
                            <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
                            <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                                <i class="icon icon_search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </form>
                    </li>

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="http://mioutlets.cl" style="color: #fff !important;">Inicio</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Accesorios" style="color: #fff !important;">Accesorios</a>
                    </li> <!-- end categories -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Funcional" style="color: #fff !important;">Funcional</a>
                    </li> <!-- end categories -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Pesas" style="color: #fff !important;">Pesas</a>
                    </li> <!-- end categories -->

                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/contact" style="color: #fff !important;">Contáctenos</a>
                    </li>

                    <li class="mobile-links">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="http://mioutlets.cl/login">INGRESAR</a></li>
                            <li><a href="http://mioutlets.cl/register">REGISTRATE</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul> <!-- end menu -->
            </div> <!-- end collapse -->
        </div> <!-- end col -->

    </div> <!-- end row -->
</div>
```

Entonces, la solución fue mover el `nav-wrap` que estaba dentro de `header-wrap-holder` y hacerlo su elemento hermano.

```html
<div class="header-wrap" style="background: #fff !important;">
    <div class="header-wrap-holder" style="margin-top: 20px !important; background: #fff !important;">
        <!-- Logo -->
        <div class="logo-container text-left">

            <a href="http://mioutlets.cl">
                <img class="hidden-xs" style="height: 150px !important; padding-left: 80px !important;"
                    src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/1598588156.png" alt="logo">

                <img class="logo hidden-md hidden-lg" style="height: 150px !important; padding-left: 80px !important;"
                    src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/1598588156.png" alt="logo">
            </a>

        </div>


        <!-- Search -->
        <div class="nav-search hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <form action="http://mioutlets.cl/product/all" method="post">
                <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="vW2kK9yCh4BFkzd2bTTLjRpQJ6dbyooTRsO9dpQQ">
                <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar" style="width: 500px !important;">
                <button type="submit" class="search-button push-right">
                    <i class="icon icon_search"></i>
                </button>
            </form>

        </div>


        <!-- Cart -->
        <div class="nav-cart-wrap hidden-sm hidden-xs">
            <div class="nav-cart right">
                <div class="nav-cart-outer">
                    <div class="nav-cart-inner">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-cart-icon">2</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-cart-container">
                    <div class="nav-cart-items">
                        <div class="nav-cart-item clearfix">
                            <div class="nav-cart-img">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <img src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/2020-08-11-05-41-12-file.jpg" alt="">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-title">
                                <a href="#">
                                    BANDA RESISTENCIA
                                </a>
                                <div class="nav-cart-price">
                                    <span>1 x</span>
                                    <span>$ 9990</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-remove">
                                <a href="#"><i class="icon icon_close"></i></a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="nav-cart-item clearfix">
                                <div class="nav-cart-img">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        <img src="http://mioutlets.cl/public/files/2020-08-11-11-23-31-file.jpg" alt="">
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-cart-title">
                                    <a href="#">
                                        PELOTA YOGA 65 CM
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="nav-cart-price">
                                        <span>1 x</span>
                                        <span>$ 7990</span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="nav-cart-remove">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="icon icon_close"></i></a>
                                </div>

                            </div> <!-- end cart items -->

                            <div class="nav-cart-summary">
                                <span>Subtotal</span>
                                <span class="total-price">$ 17980</span>
                            </div>

                            <div class="nav-cart-actions mt-20">
                                <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/cart" class="btn btn-md btn-dark"><span>Ver
                                        Carro</span></a>
                                <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/checkout" class="btn btn-md btn-color mt-10"><span>Ir a
                                        Pagar</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="menu-cart-amount right">
                        <span>
                            Carro /
                            <a href="#"> $ 17980</a>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- end cart -->

            </div>
        </div> <!-- end header wrap -->

        <!-- end col -->

    </div>
    <div class="nav-wrap" style="background: #CC384D !important;">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                <li id="mobile-search" class="hidden-lg hidden-md">
                    <form action="http://mioutlets.cl/product/all" method="post" class="mobile-search relative">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="vW2kK9yCh4BFkzd2bTTLjRpQJ6dbyooTRsO9dpQQ">
                        <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Buscar...">
                        <button type="submit" class="search-button">
                            <i class="icon icon_search"></i>
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl" style="color: #fff !important;">Inicio</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Accesorios" style="color: #fff !important;">Accesorios</a>
                </li> <!-- end categories -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Funcional" style="color: #fff !important;">Funcional</a>
                </li> <!-- end categories -->
                <li>
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/category/Pesas" style="color: #fff !important;">Pesas</a>
                </li> <!-- end categories -->

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="http://mioutlets.cl/contact" style="color: #fff !important;">Contáctenos</a>
                </li>

                <li class="mobile-links">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="http://mioutlets.cl/login">INGRESAR</a></li>
                        <li><a href="http://mioutlets.cl/register">REGISTRATE</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul> <!-- end menu -->
        </div> <!-- end collapse -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div>
```

De esa manera, aunque tengas más elementos en el carrito ya se visualiza bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: amigo me salvastes!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Muchisimas gracias!!!! @Noob Dev